# # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: C#->C++/CLI Wrapper->Java

Tags: java, c#, java-native-interface, c++-cli

So this is the error I get on Eclipse:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (0xe0434352), pid=7696, tid=8632
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b15) (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc42d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
```

This is the C# dll:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StringAPI
{
    public class Test
    {
        public string Something(string username)
        {
            return username;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class String_Displayer
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("StringAPIWrapper");
    }

    public native String something(String username);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String_Displayer sd = new String_Displayer();
        System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String username = scan.next();
        String s = sd.something(username);
        System.out.print(sd.something(username));
    }
```

And this is the C++/CLI Wrapper:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "com_StringDisplayer_String_Displayer.h"
#include "StringAPIWrapper.h"
#include <vcclr.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace StringAPI;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_StringDisplayer_String_1Displayer_something (JNIEnv *env, jclass jc, jstring js)
{
    const jchar* temp = (env)->GetStringChars(js, 0); 
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    String^ managedString = gcnew System::String((const wchar_t*)temp);
    env->ReleaseStringChars(js, temp);
    Test^ test1 = gcnew Test();
    String^ result = test1->Something(managedString);

    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> resultChars = PtrToStringChars(result);
    return env->NewString((jchar*)resultChars, result->Length);
}
```

What I'm sure of is the function that calls the C# function is working properly. I've also tried to just write it directly from C++/CLI using `System::Console::Writeline` without converting to a jstring but it didn't work. I know that using Writeline does actually work: If I do `System::Console::WriteLine("test");` and comment out the call to C#, "test" is written to the console.

Comment: Can you do a test with a boatload of debugging prints? I'd like to see the value of the string in Java, the `wchar_t*` array in C++/CLI, the value of the first `wchar_t` in the array, the `String^`, the String in C#, and everything on the way back as well. (I'm assuming these will be flushed to the console before the JRE crashes.)

Comment: Sure but could you please tell me how to run the test?

Comment: By the way, do you want me to post the error log that java produced?

Comment: As with most writeline debugging, run the application as you normally do. You could attach a debugger to it to get the information instead, but since you're moving through three different languages, debugging that isn't the easiest thing, so outputting a boatload of information to the console as the application runs is the next best thing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really not sure how to do that exactly. do I do this through eclipse?

Comment: Take your existing code. Add a bunch of calls to `System.out.println` in Java, `Console::WriteLine` in C++/CLI, and `Console.WriteLine` in C#. Edit the code in your question to include those calls, and to tell us what the result is.

Comment: Nothing happened. I still get the same error. I might be doing it wrong though. Could you please edit the code in the question to sow me exactly what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this?